# Adding C binding to H3 Rust library

Tags: c, rust, h3

I'm attempting to add the kRing function (amongst others) to an existing Rust project that implements a C-binding of the Uber H3 library. Here's the original source: https://github.com/scottmmjackson/h3api

Here are my very newbish additions:

````rust
extern crate libc;

#[macro_use]
extern crate failure;

use std::ffi::CString;
use std::fmt;
use std::str;

use libc::{c_char, c_int, c_ulonglong, size_t};

#[link(name = "h3")]
extern "C" {
    // Indexing.
    fn geoToH3(g: *const GeoCoordInternal, res: c_int) -> c_ulonglong;
    fn h3ToGeo(h3: c_ulonglong, g: *mut GeoCoordInternal);
    fn h3ToGeoBoundary(h3: c_ulonglong, gp: *mut GeoBoundaryInternal);

    // Inspection.
    fn h3GetResolution(h: c_ulonglong) -> c_int;
    fn h3GetBaseCell(h: c_ulonglong) -> c_int;
    fn stringToH3(str: *const c_char) -> c_ulonglong;
    fn h3ToString(h: c_ulonglong, str: *const c_char, sz: size_t);
    fn h3IsValid(h: c_ulonglong) -> c_int;
    fn h3IsResClassIII(h: c_ulonglong) -> c_int;
    fn h3IsPentagon(h: c_ulonglong) -> c_int;

    // Traversal.
    fn h3Distance(origin: c_ulonglong, h3: c_ulonglong) -> c_int;
    fn kRing(origin: c_ulonglong, k: c_int, h3: [ *mut c_ulonglong; 6 ]);

    // Hierarchy.
    fn h3ToParent(h: c_ulonglong, parentRes: c_int) -> c_ulonglong;
}

const DEG_TO_RAD: f64 = std::f64::consts::PI / 180.0;
const RAD_TO_DEG: f64 = 180.0 / std::f64::consts::PI;

// Maximum number of cell boundary vertices. The worst case is a pentagon: 5 original verts
// and 5 edge crossings.
const MAX_CELL_BNDRY_VERTS: usize = 10;

/// H3Index is a point in the H3 geospatial indexing system.
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
pub struct H3Index(u64);

impl H3Index {
    /// Creates a new `H3Index` from the given point. If the point is not a valid index in
    /// H3 then `None` is returned.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::H3Index;
    ///
    /// let h = H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap();
    /// ```
    pub fn new(h: u64) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let valid;
        unsafe {
            valid = h3IsValid(h);
        }
        if valid == 0 {
            return Err(Error::InvalidIndex { value: h });
        }
        Ok(Self(h))
    }

    /// Converts a string to an H3 index.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::H3Index;
    ///
    /// assert_eq!(
    ///   H3Index::from_str("0x850dab63fffffff").unwrap(),
    ///   H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap()
    /// )
    /// ```
    pub fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let c_str = match CString::new(s) {
            Ok(c_str) => c_str,
            Err(_) => {
                return Err(Error::InvalidString {
                    value: s.to_owned(),
                })
            }
        };

        let h;
        unsafe {
            h = stringToH3(c_str.as_ptr());
        }

        if h == 0 {
            return Err(Error::InvalidString {
                value: s.to_owned(),
            });
        }
        return Ok(H3Index(h));
    }

    /// Finds the centroid of the index.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::{GeoCoord, H3Index};
    ///
    /// let h = H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap();
    /// assert_eq!(h.to_geo(), GeoCoord::new(67.15092686397712, -168.39088858096966));
    /// ```
    pub fn to_geo(self) -> GeoCoord {
        let mut geo = GeoCoordInternal::new(0.0, 0.0);
        unsafe {
            h3ToGeo(self.0, &mut geo);
        }
        geo.to_deg()
    }

    /// Finds the boundary of the index.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    ///  // TODO
    /// ```
    pub fn to_geo_boundary(self) -> GeoBoundary {
        let mut gb = GeoBoundaryInternal::new();
        unsafe {
            h3ToGeoBoundary(self.0, &mut gb);
        }
        gb.convert()
    }

    /// Returns the resolution of the index.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::H3Index;
    ///
    /// let h = H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap();
    /// assert_eq!(h.resolution(), 5);
    /// ```
    pub fn resolution(self) -> i32 {
        unsafe { h3GetResolution(self.0) }
    }

    /// Returns the base cell number of the index.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::H3Index;
    ///
    /// let h = H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap();
    /// assert_eq!(h.base_cell(), 6);
    /// ```
    pub fn base_cell(self) -> i32 {
        unsafe { h3GetBaseCell(self.0) }
    }

    /// Returns a `bool` indicating whether this index has a resolution with a Class
    /// III orientation.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::H3Index;
    ///
    /// assert!(H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap().is_res_class_3());
    /// ```
    pub fn is_res_class_3(self) -> bool {
        unsafe { h3IsResClassIII(self.0) != 0 }
    }

    /// Returns a `bool` indicating whether this index represents a pentagonal cell.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::H3Index;
    ///
    /// assert!(H3Index::new(0x821c07fffffffff).unwrap().is_pentagon());
    /// assert!(!H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap().is_pentagon());
    /// ```
    pub fn is_pentagon(self) -> bool {
        unsafe { h3IsPentagon(self.0) != 0 }
    }

    /// Returns the distance in grid cells between two indexes or an error if finding the
    /// distance fails. Finding the distance can fail because the two indexes are not comparable
    /// (different resolutions), too far apart, or are separated by pentagonal distortion.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// // TODO
    /// ```
    pub fn distance(self, other: Self) -> Result<i32, Error> {
        let d;
        unsafe {
            d = h3Distance(self.0, other.0);
        }

        if d < 0 {
            return Err(Error::IncompatibleIndexes {
                left: self,
                right: other,
            });
        }
        Ok(d)
    }

    pub fn krings(self, index: i32) -> [H3Index; 6] {
        let values: [*mut u64; 6] = array_init::array_init(|_| -> *mut u64 {
            let val: *mut u64 = &mut u64::default();
            val
        });
        unsafe {
            kRing(self.0, index, values);
        }
        let h3s: [H3Index; 6] = array_init::array_init(|i| -> H3Index {
            let val = H3Index(values[i] as u64);
            println!("{}", val); // printing out the resulting H3Index value to study
            val
        });
        h3s
    }

    /// Returns the parent (coarser) index containing h.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// // TODO
    /// ```
    pub fn parent(self, res: i32) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let h;
        unsafe {
            h = h3ToParent(self.0, res);
        }

        if h == 0 {
            return Err(Error::FailedConversion);
        }
        Ok(Self(h))
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for H3Index {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; 17];
        unsafe {
            h3ToString(self.0, buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut i8, buf.capacity());
        }
        let res = String::from_utf8(buf);
        let s = res
            .as_ref()
            .map(|s| s.trim_end_matches('\0'))
            .unwrap_or("<invalid>");
        write!(f, "{}", s)
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct GeoCoordInternal {
    pub lat: f64,
    pub lon: f64,
}

impl GeoCoordInternal {
    pub fn new(lat: f64, lon: f64) -> Self {
        Self { lat, lon }
    }

    fn to_deg(&self) -> GeoCoord {
        GeoCoord::new(self.lat * RAD_TO_DEG, self.lon * RAD_TO_DEG)
    }

    fn to_h3(&self, res: i32) -> H3Index {
        unsafe { H3Index(geoToH3(self, res)) }
    }
}

/// GeoCoord is a point on the earth. It is comprised of a latitude and longitude expressed in
/// degrees. The C API for H3 expects the latitude and longitude to be expressed in radians so
/// the coordinates are transparently converted to radians before being passed to the C library.
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct GeoCoord {
    pub lat: f64,
    pub lon: f64,
}

impl GeoCoord {
    /// Creates a new `GeoCoord` from the given latitude and longitude. The unit of the
    /// coordinates is degrees.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::GeoCoord;
    ///
    /// let mut coord: GeoCoord = GeoCoord::new(67.194013596, 191.598258018);
    /// ```
    pub fn new(lat: f64, lon: f64) -> Self {
        Self { lat, lon }
    }

    fn to_radians(&self) -> GeoCoordInternal {
        GeoCoordInternal::new(self.lat * DEG_TO_RAD, self.lon * DEG_TO_RAD)
    }

    /// Indexes the location at the specified resolution.
    ///
    /// # Example
    ///
    /// ```
    /// extern crate h3_rs as h3;
    /// use h3::{GeoCoord, H3Index};
    ///
    /// let mut coord: GeoCoord = GeoCoord::new(67.194013596, 191.598258018);
    /// assert_eq!(coord.to_h3(5).unwrap(), H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap());
    /// ```
    pub fn to_h3(&self, res: i32) -> Result<H3Index, Error> {
        let index = self.to_radians().to_h3(res);
        if index.0 == 0 {
            return Err(Error::FailedConversion);
        }
        return Ok(index);
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct GeoBoundaryInternal {
    num_verts: i32,
    verts: [GeoCoordInternal; MAX_CELL_BNDRY_VERTS],
}

impl GeoBoundaryInternal {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            num_verts: 0,
            verts: [GeoCoordInternal::new(0.0, 0.0); MAX_CELL_BNDRY_VERTS],
        }
    }

    fn convert(&self) -> GeoBoundary {
        let mut verts = Vec::with_capacity(self.num_verts as usize);
        for i in 0..self.num_verts {
            verts.push(self.verts[i as usize].to_deg());
        }
        GeoBoundary { verts }
    }
}

/// GeoBoundary is a collection of points which defines the boundary of a cell.
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct GeoBoundary {
    pub verts: Vec<GeoCoord>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
pub enum Error {
    #[fail(display = "invalid value for H3 index: {}", value)]
    InvalidIndex { value: u64 },
    #[fail(display = "invalid string representation of H3 index: {}", value)]
    InvalidString { value: String },
    #[fail(display = "could not convert to H3 index")]
    FailedConversion,
    #[fail(display = "h3 indexes are incompatible: {} and {}", left, right)]
    IncompatibleIndexes { left: H3Index, right: H3Index },
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    struct Setup {
        valid_index: H3Index,
        pentagon_index: H3Index,
        valid_geo_coord: GeoCoord,
    }

    impl Setup {
        fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                valid_index: H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap(),
                pentagon_index: H3Index::new(0x821c07fffffffff).unwrap(),
                valid_geo_coord: GeoCoord::new(67.15092686397712, -168.39088858096966),
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_from_str() {
        assert_eq!(
            H3Index::from_str("0x850dab63fffffff").unwrap(),
            H3Index::new(0x850dab63fffffff).unwrap()
        );
        assert!(H3Index::from_str("invalid string").is_err());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_to_geo() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        assert_eq!(setup.valid_index.to_geo(), setup.valid_geo_coord);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_to_geo_boundary() {
        // TODO
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_resolution() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        for res in 0..16 {
            let h = setup.valid_geo_coord.to_h3(res).unwrap();
            assert_eq!(h.resolution(), res);
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_base_cell() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        assert_eq!(setup.valid_index.base_cell(), 6);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_is_res_class_3() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        assert!(setup.valid_index.is_res_class_3());

        // TODO: Test an index which should return from false. From the Go package:
        // res := Resolution(validH3Index) - 1
        // parent := ToParent(validH3Index, res)
        // assert.False(t, IsResClassIII(parent))
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_is_pentagon() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        assert!(!setup.valid_index.is_pentagon());
        assert!(setup.pentagon_index.is_pentagon());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_distance() {
        // let setup = Setup::new();

        // TODO
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_parent() {
        // let setup = Setup::new();

        // TODO
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_h3_display() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        assert_eq!(format!("{}", setup.valid_index), "850dab63fffffff");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_geo_to_h3() {
        let setup = Setup::new();

        assert_eq!(setup.valid_geo_coord.to_h3(5).unwrap(), setup.valid_index);
        assert!(setup.valid_geo_coord.to_h3(-1).is_err());
        assert!(setup.valid_geo_coord.to_h3(17).is_err());
    }
}

fn main() {

    // geoToH3 --resolution 6 --latitude 43.6411124 --longitude -79.4180424
    let _coord = GeoCoordInternal{ lat: 43.6411124, lon: -79.4180424 };
    let index = _coord.to_h3(6); // 862b9bc57ffffff
    // kRing -k 1 --origin 862b9bc57ffffff
    let _first = index.krings(1);
    // 862b9bc57ffffff
    // 862b9bc0fffffff
    // 862b9bce7ffffff
    // 862b9bcefffffff
    // 862b9bc5fffffff
    // 862b9bc47ffffff
    // 862b9bc77ffffff

    println!("{}", index);

}
````

You can see I add the definition in the extern "C" block:

```rust
fn kRing(origin: c_ulonglong, k: c_int, h3: [ *mut c_ulonglong; 6 ]);
```

I figured `[ *mut c_ulonglong; 6 ]` is appropriate because the documentation at https://h3geo.org/#/documentation/api-reference/traversal has an interface of `void kRing(H3Index origin, int k, H3Index* out);` where out is a mutable array of H3Index.

Once the C function is declared I attempt using it:

```rust
pub fn krings(self, index: i32) -> [H3Index; 6] {
    let values: [*mut u64; 6] = array_init::array_init(|_| -> *mut u64 {
        let val: *mut u64 = &mut u64::default();
        val
    });
    unsafe {
        kRing(self.0, index, values);
    }
    let h3s: [H3Index; 6] = array_init::array_init(|i| -> H3Index {
        let val = H3Index(values[i] as u64);
        println!("{}", val);
        val
    });
    h3s
}
```

In my main I then run through the process of grabbing an H3 index for some defined coordinates  then grabbing the kring:

```rust
let _coord = GeoCoordInternal{ lat: 43.6411124, lon: -79.4180424 };
let index = _coord.to_h3(6);
```

The result of this should be `862b9bc57ffffff`. Then I call my krings method with a k value of 1 (which should return 6 values).

The values I get are:

```
7ffeeace1ea8
7ffeeace1ea8
7ffeeace1ea8
7ffeeace1ea8
7ffeeace1ea8
7ffeeace1ea8
```

Which seems to be an incorrect return value. The correct values I'm looking for are:

```
862b9bc57ffffff
862b9bc0fffffff
862b9bce7ffffff
862b9bcefffffff
862b9bc5fffffff
862b9bc47ffffff
862b9bc77ffffff
```

I believe the incorrect values are just the index representations based on u64::default() indicating that the array isn't being populated.

I'm also getting unsafe FFI errors which I'm not sure how to handle and I believe are the reason why I'm having incorrect values returned.

[image]

Note that the logic above will inevitably change. The array size will have to be dynamic/unspecified because the size of the array returned by the C function changes based on the value of k (k * 6 + 1 to be precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mcarton had a lot of really great points. I found another libh3 that implemented these properly. Here's example of a properly implemented kring function:

```
pub fn kring(origin:H3Index, radius: i32) -> Vec<H3Index> {
    unsafe {
        let max = libh3_sys::maxKringSize(radius);
        let mut r = Vec::<H3Index>::with_capacity(max as usize);
        kRing(origin, radius, r.as_mut_ptr());
        r.set_len(max as usize);
        r = r.into_iter().filter(|v| *v != 0).collect();
        return r;
    }
}
```

Beyond mcarton's points using a Vector to store and return index values was necessary.

Comment: how does `maxKringSize` determine the resolution? Will it calculate the number of indices on finest granularity?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- The first one is obviously the one reported by the warning: C does not have first class arrays, therefore you cannot pass Rust arrays to a C function. You need to use [`[T]::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr) to pass a pointer to your array to the C function.
- ```rust
  {
      let val: *mut u64 = &mut u64::default();
      val
  }
  ```

  creates a pointer to a temporary value. Using this pointer is instant UB.
- `pub struct H3Index(u64);` is *not* ABI compatible with `u64` or `c_ulonglong`. You'd need to add [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent) to the structure declaration for that.
- `H3Index*` is a pointer to an array of `H3Index`, but you are passing an array of pointer of `H3Index` to your function.

Comment: Yeah most of your comments make sense now. Apologies very much a noob to Rust and C just wrapping my head around all this. I appreciate the guidance.